# Duplicate GA4 purchase event on first purchase only

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I'm encountering an issue with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) on my WordPress website where the purchase event is being triggered twice on the first purchase, but subsequent purchases by the same user only trigger the purchase event once, as expected. I'm using the following gtag test script to send the purchase event:

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        'currency': 'USD',
        'value': 1,
        'transaction_id': '1234',
        'items': [
            {
                'item_id': 'SKU-001',
                'item_name': 'Example Product',
                'quantity': 1,
                'price': 1
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

If it helps I noticed that the ga_session_id and ga_session_number appear twice for the first purchase, while other parameters like currency and page_title only appear once.

I've tested this with a custom script and without any GTM involvement.

I've checked for duplicate gtag scripts in the website's source code and I've tried disabling all plugins and switching to the default WordPress theme to isolate the issue, but the problem persists.

None of these seem to be the cause of the problem. I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the GA4 purchase event is only triggered once for all purchases, regardless of whether they are the user's first purchase or not.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.